# Изменяю плавно ширину блока. Как проявлять блок с конца, а не с начала?

Tags: css

Показываю блок с изменением его ширины. Что бы плавно выезжал. Так вот изменение ширины происходит слева направо. Можно сделать наоборот? 
В коде клик на квадрат.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.input').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}

input {
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition:.2s;
}

input.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.input').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}

input {
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0; /* Добавил вот эту строчку */
  opacity: 0;
  transition:.2s;
}

input.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}

input {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 5s;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -21px
}

input.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.input').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```